# Automatically choosing subranges from a list based on a maximum value in the subrange

Tags: python-3.x, list, pandas

I am pretty new to Python and want to fix weekly regular prices (RPs) of a product.  The RPs in current and desired forms are shown as blue and red lines, respectively, in [Figure for Weekly_RPs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8TpIF.png). The corresponding 52 weeks of data, and minimal code are following:

```
Weeks= list(range(1,53))
RegPriceNow=[5.99, 4.99, 4.99, 5.99, 5.99, 5.99, 5.99, 5.99, 4.99, 4.99, 
             6.49, 6.49, 6.49, 6.49, 6.49, 6.49, 6.49, 6.49, 6.49, 6.49, 
             5.49, 5.49, 6.49, 5.49, 6.49, 6.49, 6.49, 6.49, 5.49, 5.49, 
             5.99, 6.49, 5.99, 6.49, 6.49, 6.99, 6.99, 6.99, 6.99, 6.99, 
             6.99, 6.99, 6.49, 6.49, 5.79, 5.79, 5.99, 5.99, 5.99, 5.79, 
             5.99, 5.99]

list1=[5.99]*10
list2=[6.49]*25
list3=[6.99]*9
list4=[5.99]*8
RegPriceExp=list1+list2+list3+list4 

print('The desired output is ',RegPriceExp)
plt.plot(Weeks,RegPriceNow,color='blue',label='RegPrice Now')
plt.plot(Weeks,RegPriceExp,linestyle='-.',color='red',label='RegPrice Exp')
```

The RP rules are:

- A RP is supposed to maintain for 4 weeks at least
- A value between two RPs should prefer previous RP, for example, weeks 43, 44 were having value 6.49 between RP-6.99 and RP-5.99, and they preferred 6.99

Sub-ranges can visually be found for desired RPs but some automation is needed here to deal with the hundreds of such products. Any clever idea would be appreciated to deal with this issue.

Comment: do you have an example of desired output?

Comment: Desired output is `RegPriceExp` in code